# jQuery - subtract value of data upon a selection

Tags: jquery, variables, var, addition

I'm wondering if it is possible to add to a value upon the selection of a drop down list.

For example:
If one of the following are selected..

```
<select class="item_print-colour">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Print Colour..</option>
    <option value="B&W" value="Print Colour:"> Black And White </option>
    <option value="Full-Colour"> Full Colour </option>
</select>
```

I would like the following data-base_price to be increased by 0.20:

```
<span class="item_price cd_price" data-base_price="0.53"></span>
```

**What I have already tried** 
but no matter what I try I can't get it to change upon a select:

```
$(".item_print-colour").on("select", function() {
    var base_price = $(".cd_price").data("base_price");
    var addition = 0;

    if (this.value = B&W) addition = 0.20;
    $(".cd_price").text((base_price + addition).toFixed(2));
    }).trigger("select");
```

**EDIT**

I also have other factors determining the data-base_price, which is why I am trying to add to whatever is currently in data-base_price.

Comment: Are you sure your code is firing properly?  I see conflicting element IDs between your HTML and jQuery.

Comment: @RobB EDITED - Sorry that was me not proof reading...

Answer (score 1):

- `on('change'...` not select
- `if(this.value == 'B&W')`
- you can refactor to: `base_price += 0.2;`
- you don't need to `trigger('select');`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just missed the quotes?

```
if (this.value == "B&W")
...
```

Comment: Also needs a double equals, `==`.

Comment: @Orbling Fixed that aswell. But now I see that there may be more incorrect things in OP's question. I'll review to post a more complete answer

Comment: Aye, there's a few things.  God knows why someone voted this down though.. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(".dvd_case_quantity").on("change", function() {
    var base_price = $(".cd_price").data("base_price");
    var addition = (this.value == 'B&W' ? 0.20 : 0);
    var newPrice = (base_price + addition).toFixed(2);
    $(".cd_price").text(newPrice);
});
```

Note: The above solution separates the `newPrice` into a separate variable.  You can keep it as-is, but I try to employ a more debug friendly style which will make testing much easier.